# getElementById that contains "abc" android onbackpressed

Tags: javascript, java, android

this is my onBackPressed:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (Config.EXIT_APP_BY_BACK_BUTTON_ALWAYS) {

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                    "l=document.getElementById('sdf_1422');"+
                    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                    "})()");

}}
```

This works very well but the problem is that my page contains a lot of div's of sdf_1422, sdf_1423, sdf_1424, and so on. Can you help my to get all the sdf_, and click them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the elements you are looking for with `document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=sdf_]")` This is looking for all divs with id **starting with** sdf_ . This function returns a nodelist.

You can iterate a nodelist and add an event to every node:

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=sdf_]");
list.forEach(element => { element.addEventListener('click', () => {}) })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done what you said. Not working at this time.